# How to get IP addresses from SCVMM 2008 R2

Tags: powershell, ip, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I took IP addresses from Hyper-V 2008 R2 Stand alone using PowerShell with this library: https://pshyperv.codeplex.com/

It is possible to get IP Addresses from SCVMM 2008 R2 using Windows PowerShell-Virtual Machine Manager?
There exist a library similary with pshyperv.codeplex.com from SCVMM 2008 R2?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this works with Hyper-V 2008R2 but it works with 2012R2.

First run:

```
Import-Module virtualmachinemanager
```

Than you can try either:

```
Get-VM  | Get-VirtualNetworkAdapter | select name,ipv4addresses
```

or:

```
Get-SCVirtualMachine | Get-SCVirtualNetworkAdapter | select name,ipv4Addresses
```